# Blender Internal. How do I add a texture for part of the object, while keeping the rest of the texture

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

Can someone tell me how to overlay the texture for the eyes? If I go to texture, the outfit isn't there. I have the same problem with other textures as well.

[image]

Comment: @susu good catch, I hadn't noticed it was for blender internal. Reopened, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is the following:

1. Add a new material for your object.
2. Assign the new material to the eyes.
3. Create a new texture.
4. In the `Shading` workspace, add your texture to the new material you created using a `Image Texture` node.

If you want more in-depth instructions, let me know.

Comment: Another recommendation: Update Blender.